# How can I understand if my system is using jBoss?

Tags: linux, process, disk-usage, webserver, jboss

I have just noticed there is no space available in my server, therefore I need to remove something.

It seems the `/opt/jboss-6.1.0` directory is taking more than 200Gb (unbelievable).

I would like to remove it, but I am not sure if the server is using jBoss (I don't even know what it is).
How can I understand if removing this folder will cause problems to the server? (I know we are using Apache Web Server)

I have checked processes with: `ps aux | grep jboss` but nothing is found.

Comment: probably using it, probably logs that can be cleaned up. Do not erase the entire directory

Comment: You are right! the logs are taking all the space!! Thank you so much

Comment: Which is the log directory?

Comment: /opt/jboss-6.1.0/server/all/log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JBoss is an application server, a framework for running Java-based applications/servlets. So basically erasing that `/opt/jboss-xxx` most certainly means deleting the entire application (depending on the configuration of your server)

see [JBoss Enterprise Application Platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform)

JBoss is probably running, and as more than usual, you have it full of logs. Application servers also need to have regular scrubbing and maintenance, specially when it comes to logs grooming (log rotation configured, or cron jobs cleaning it up).

Your ps/grep command may not have worked because grep is case sensitive. I would recommend:

```
ps -uax | egrep -i "jboss|java"
```

The JBoss process might also be dead because logging space is exhausted.

As for logs, I would recommend a regular cron job, cleaning up logs with more than 2 months (60 days actually), as in:

```
find /opt/jboss-6.1.0/server/all/log -type f -mtime +60 -exec rm {} \;
```

Relevant link:

[Delete Files Older Than x Days on Linux](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/delete-files-older-than-x-days-on-linux/)

Disclaimer: such log scrubbing should be part of a policy of regular backups.

Comment: amazing, thank you so much for your help! very clear

Comment: The answer failed to explain what JBoss is, corrected.